# Are there any common erros in JQuery XSLT?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, xslt

I'm having a problem with a JQuery plugin on a frontend-xslt-site in Firefox. Are there any common errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it turns out that firefox is the only browser that complies to standard and doesn't support document.write in xhtml. It turns out to be a pretty common problem!